# Is there a service for converting IP address to timezone name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, ip-address, activesupport

I'm finding a service that converts IP address of clients into timezone names for use in a Rails web app. I found a couple of them, like [ipinfodb](http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php), but they just provide the timezones **"time offset"** (e.g. +0700). But what I need is the actual **timezone name** or, at least, its **abbreviation** (e.g. Indochina Time or ICT). Is there any API out there, or may be a database that I can use for this?

I need to match the timezone of two objects. Those timezones can be anywhere in the world. One of them is a **ActiveSupport timezone name**, BUT another one is just a **time offset**. And time offset doesn't have **DST** information I need so I can't match them correctly.